# Perl abs_path undefined return using File::Find::dir value from relative directory

Tags: perl

A Perl script running on macOS takes a directory argument and then calls the `File::Find` `&wanted()` function to process the contents.

If I supply the directory as an absolute path (e.g. `"/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT"`) I have no problems.

But if I supply a relative path (i.e. `"."` when run from above directory) I get an error.

The error happens when processing a file in a subdirectory: it is always the first file in the particular subdirectory (the first second level subdirectory) that generates the error (if I create or touch a new file with an alphabetically earlier name than any existing one in the directory, it is this new file that causes the error). Many earlier files are processed OK.

Complete simplified code below, with output.

So why does the below "abs_path" call give an undefined result for this one particular file (first file in first second level subdirectory)?

### COMPLETE CODE:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use English;
use vars qw ( $VERSION );
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Find;
find({ wanted => \&processFile, follow => 0 }, $ARGV[0]); #we do NOT follow symbolic links
exit();
sub processFile
{
    if (substr($_,0,1) eq ".") { return; } #ignore entry starting with dot 
    print "\nPROCESSING WITH:\n";
    print ">> \$File::Find::dir = <<$File::Find::dir>>\n";
    print ">> \$_ = <<$_>>\n";
    print ">> \$File::Find::name=<<$File::Find::name>>\n";
    my $dirAbsPath=abs_path($File::Find::dir);
    die "ERROR: undef abs_path() using Find::File::dir value!\n" if ! defined $dirAbsPath;
    print "Dir Abs Path is <<$dirAbsPath>>\n";
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
PROCESSING WITH:
>> $File::Find::dir = <<.>>
>> $_ = <<L1DIR>>
>> $File::Find::name=<<./L1DIR>>
Dir Abs Path is <</Users/sw/Downloads/FGT>>

PROCESSING WITH:
>> $File::Find::dir = <<./L1DIR>>
>> $_ = <<LPT1.csv>>
>> $File::Find::name=<<./L1DIR/LPT1.csv>>
Dir Abs Path is <</Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/L1DIR/L1DIR>>

PROCESSING WITH:
>> $File::Find::dir = <<./L1DIR>>
>> $_ = <<L2DIR2>>
>> $File::Find::name=<<./L1DIR/L2DIR2>>
Dir Abs Path is <</Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/L1DIR/L1DIR>>

PROCESSING WITH:
>> $File::Find::dir = <<./L1DIR/L2DIR2>>
>> $_ = <<abc>>
>> $File::Find::name=<<./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc>>
ERROR: undef abs_path() using Find::File::dir value!
```

### DIRECTORY TREE OF ".":

```
sw@Max FGT % tree .
.
└── L1DIR
    ├── L2DIR1
    │   └── LD.csv
    ├── L2DIR2
    │   ├── abc
    │   └── x.csv
    ├── L2DIR3
    │   └── xsym2 -> T2/x.csv
    └── LPT1.csv
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code formatting, as much as possible since it's not clear to me what it is meant to convey.  (And what are those backslashes in `File::Find`'s variable names?)  I also removed the last paragraph of complaints about code formatting.  If you don't like my edits you can undo them by going to "edited ..." link above my username and rolling back.  Or edit as you please of course.

Comment: Complete code that runs now included, kind of almost got the formatting correct!

Comment: I have found a workaround, but still want to know why the original code does not work:
The work around is to call cwd(): that returns expected result (since File::Find cd's into each directory by default).
But it isn't clear why cwd() works where abs_path($File::Find:dir) returns undef!

Comment: Note the second and third absolute paths are also wrong. There is no `/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/L1DIR/L1DIR`. (Note the duplicate `L1DIR`.) Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$File::Find::dir` is relative to the original CWD. But File::Find changes the CWD unless you use `no_chdir => 1`.

---

When processing `./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc` with `no_chdir => 0` (default),

- The CWD is `$orig_cwd/./L1DIR/L2DIR2`.
- `$File::Find::name` is `./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc`.
- `$File::Find::dir` is `./L1DIR/L2DIR2`.
- `$_` is `abc`.

(Where `$orig_cwd` is the absolute path of `.` before you call `find`.)

So that means that `abs_path( $File::Find::dir )` is the absolute path of `$orig_cwd/./L1DIR/L2DIR2/./L1DIR/L2DIR2`, which obviously fails.

Using `abs_path(".")` would work.

---

When processing `./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc` with `no_chdir => 1`,

- The CWD is `$orig_cwd`.
- `$File::Find::name` is `./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc`.
- `$File::Find::dir` is `./L1DIR/L2DIR2`.
- `$_` is `./L1DIR/L2DIR2/abc`.

So that means that `abs_path( $File::Find::dir )` is the absolute path of `$orig_cwd/./L1DIR/L2DIR2`, which is what you want.

I prefer to avoid all those needless `chdir`, I prefer using `no_chdir => 1` at all times.

Comment: Yes, but that should not cause a problem: original dir is <<.>> (dot), so as per original post you see the directory value after going into the second level subdir is <<./FGT_22/TT2>>.
I will say it is the first second level directory to be processed: so the first file in the first second level directory. Still don't see why that would be an issue.

Comment: That would most definitely fail. There is no directory named `./FGT_22/TT2` relative to the current PWD, which is to say there is no `./FGT_22/TT2/./FGT_22/TT2` relative to the original PWD, so `abs_path` returns `undef`.

Comment: But in fact it seems that is not the issue - see this output, where you can see $File::Find::Dir value does NOT have a duplicated structure like you suggest:
>>>> $File::Find::dir = <<./L1DIR/L2DIR2>>

Comment: I never said `$File::Find::dir` is `./FGT_22/TT2/./FGT_22/TT2`. I said you are trying to find the absolute path for `$orig_cwd/./FGT_22/TT2/./FGT_22/TT2` because your CWD keeps changing.

Comment: Look, instead of disputing what I said, why don't you try the fix I suggested?

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. You may be right (although the perldoc cwd documentation is not at all clear that that is what is happening), but per my other comment, I already found a workaround: I replaced the abs_path() call with cwd()!

Comment: Re "*although the perldoc cwd documentation is not at all clear that that is what is happening*", Why would it document `find`? The documentation for File::Find documents `find`, and it does make clear that it changes the CWD.

Comment: Because I am calling abs_path() with a specific string, so does not matter what File::Find does at this  point: the question is about cwd() behaviour now. If calling abs_path(./FGT_22/TT2) when cwd is "/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/FGT_22/TT2" is bad (OK, seems like that is bad), why does it work to call abs_path(./FGT_22) when cwd is "/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/FGT_22" (which also seems like it should be bad, but it isn't!)?

Comment: The whole problem is that you didn't factor in that `find` keep changing the CWD, so it absolutely does matter what File::Find does. `cwd()` is merely returning the CWD, as it always does. And the documentation does reflect that.

Comment: Re "*which also seems like it should be bad, but it isn't!*", But it is. As I previously mention, the path you get back is wrong. You got `/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/L1DIR/L1DIR` instead of `/Users/sw/Downloads/FGT/L1DIR`

Comment: You are right, just noticed that LOL. But why the undef in one case and just the wrong path in that other case? I will mark you answer as correct and add a comment that just using cwd() instead also works!

Comment: I imagine it's because the last component of the path doesn't need to exist. But the others do. `perl -Mv5.14 -MCwd=abs_path -e'say abs_path($_)//"[undef]" for "non-existent", "non-existent/nonon-existent";'`